# Debugging Pointers with Malloc and Free

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Consider the code below:

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#define SIZE 10
int main() {
    int * p, i;
    p = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    if (p == NULL) {
      printf("malloc failed.\n");
      return 1;

    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      * (p + i) = i * i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      printf("%d\n", * p++);

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work. However I am not sure why. My professor gave an explanation that doesn't make much sense to me. Supposedly the `free` function doesn't work.

From what I understand, you can only free pointers that were created using malloc. And here we modify that pointer before sending it to free, thereby making our statement invalid.

Is this the correct way to critique that code?

Comment: Yes, every pointer value handed to `free` must exactly be a value returned from `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc` (or things like `strdup` that call `malloc`).  It's best to not modify the base pointer at all, or to save an unmodified copy of it in a separate variable.  If you like living on the edge, you could modify it but then modify it back, for example in this case by calling `free(p - SIZE)`.  (But your co-workers, or your instructors if this is an assignment you're getting graded on, will hate you.)

Comment: Are you asking about critiquing such code on [SO] or in general, say in  a lecture? If it's [SO] perhaps this question belongs on [meta]. If it's general lecture or teaching, then perhaps look at posting it to https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: One thing to note is that your `#include` lines are wrong.  Do not put any spaces between the angle brackets.  This is correct: `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And here we modify that pointer before sending it to free, thereby making our statement invalid.
>
> Is this the correct way to critique that code?

Yes, code is not freeing the original pointer allocated due to `p++` which increments the pointer with each loop iteration.

Instead, print in such a way `p` is not changed.

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  // printf("%d\n", * p++);
  printf("%d\n", p[i]);
  // or
  printf("%d\n", * (p + i));
}

// With above change, `p` is the same as the original allocated value.
free(p);
```

Comment: I think that the OP is aware of that, this feels more like a meta.stackexchange.com question

Comment: @AhmedMasud Actually, I was not aware of that. I just wanted to confirm that my reasoning was correct

Comment: :-) I was just trying to make sure that I understood the issue you had as well, chux's answer is an explanation you would give.